# Unable to figure out what is going on with Active Record distinct method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to select distinct records from models table based on user_id. I have tried writing this in few possible ways. I don't understand why using distinct with pluck[2] returns correct value, while only distinct[3] does not seem to work at all. What am I missing here?

Using 'rails', '~> 5.2.3'.

```
[1] pry(main)> Model.select(:user_id).distinct.count
   (2967.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "models"."user_id") FROM "models"
=> 11432

[2] pry(main)> Model.distinct(:user_id).pluck(:user_id).count
   (690.6ms)  SELECT DISTINCT "models"."user_id" FROM "models"
=> 11432

[3] pry(main)> Model.distinct(:user_id).count
   (1076.7ms)  SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT "models"."id") FROM "models"
=> 2531300
```

Comment: What do you mean by _select distinct records from models table based on user_id_? Does that mean you actually do not want to `count` that records but get all their data? What if there are multiple rows with the same `user_id` but the other attributes are different, which of the rows should be returned?

Comment: Sorry for confusion. I actually need the records and not the counts. It should be distinct on :user_id. I was using counts to quickly check the query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) This is the correct way to count the number of distinct `user_id` values in the database using the ActiveRecord query language.

2) Note that [`pluck`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Calculations.html#method-i-pluck) already runs the database query. That means it loads all records into memory and then counts the number of elements in that array.

3) The argument to the [`distinct`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-distinct) is not a column name but a boolean. That means that calling `distinct(:user_id)` is basically the same as calling `distinct(true)` and `true` default anyway. That means

```
Model.distinct(:user_id).count
```

is the same as

```
Model.distinct.count
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I just assumed that passing :user_id flag to distinct method would actually return distinct values on :user_id. :) I should have checked the docs before asking!